# How to comment on blogspot within an iframe with Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I would like to comment on a blogspot with selenium, chromedriver and python. I tried many methods but failed. How can I run my code below?

```
driver.get(url)
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'comment-editor')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commentBody')))

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
actionChains.move_to_element(element).send_keys(text).perform()
```

I'm getting an error on this line:

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commentBody')))
```

Please help to comment with selenium.

Edit..
test url : `https://lf2011b8308.blogspot.com/2011/12/macronutrients-carbohydrates-proteins.html`

Error stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hotto/PycharmProjects/blogspot/chromes.py", line 51, in <module>
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'commentBody')))
  File "C:\Users\Hotto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00405FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x0039E6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B3E78+802424]
    Ordinal0 [0x002E1C10+990224]
    Ordinal0 [0x002E1EAB+990891]
    Ordinal0 [0x0030EC92+1174674]
    Ordinal0 [0x002FCBD4+1100756]
    Ordinal0 [0x0030CFC2+1167298]
    Ordinal0 [0x002FC9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x002D6F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x002D7E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006A90C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0069AAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0049137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00490416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A4EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A97A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A9895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x003B26C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7697343D+18]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77729812+99]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x777297E5+54]
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: I edited and added the information you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a character sequence to the *commentBody* field as the elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  ```
  driver.get('https://clearing.apcs.at/emwebapcsem/startApp.do')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='comment-editor']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "commentBody"))).send_keys("Akif")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the error again. please help me with the code.                              
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hotto/PycharmProjects/blogspot/chromes.py", line 50, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "commentBody"))).send_keys("Akif")
  File "C:\Users\Hotto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)  @undetected-selenium